# Условие в котором проверяется, было ли использовано число

Tags: c#

Нужно написать условие в котором проверялось было ли использовано число, например, пользователь вводит 1, потом 2, и потом еще раз вводит 1, но его просят ввести другое число

Comment: `if (intVar1 == intVar2)`, м?

Comment: или `HashSet<int>`

Comment: Для небольшого набора чисел можно и `List<int>` использовать, но лучше конечно приучаться к правильным структурам типа `HashSet<int>` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так, например:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int num;
        HashSet<int> numbers = new HashSet<int>();
        do {
            do {
                num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // todo: handle exception
                if (!numbers.Add(num)) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Was earlier, try again");
                    continue;
                }
            } while (false);
            Console.WriteLine(num); 
        } while (num != 0);
        
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

[HashSet<T>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) хранит уникальное множество значений, с очень быстрыми операциями добавления и проверки наличия элемента в множестве.
Метод [Add(T)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_Add__0_) возвращает `false`, если такое значение уже есть в этом множестве.

Comment: Что делает HashSet?

Comment: Хранит уникальный набор значений. Add() возращает false, если такое значение уже есть в этом множестве.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: извините за такой вопрос, а когда программа должна закончиться ?

Comment: В данном случае, при вводе 0